# tkz-euclide and Xy-pic conflict over Babel shorthands

Tags: babel, xy-pic, tkz-euclide

It is well known that certain Babel shorthands conflict with some Xy-pic commands and this can be solved by disabling those shorthands.  I was using Xy-pic and Babel french with shorthands=off in the options list. That worked.

However, I now must combine a number of files, some written long ago using Xy-pic and some written using tkz-euclide.    The tkz-euclide will not work with shorthands=off.

The file below certainly will not compile for me, but it does work when I comment out the babel line, so I believe the shorthands problem is the reason why it does not compile:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xy}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
\xy   ,(100,0);(100,0)
        ,(97,6)="A"
        ,"A"+(-4.5,-1);"A"+(4.5,-1)  *\crv{"A"+(-3.4,-6)&"A"+(3.4,-6)}
\endxy
\end{document}
```

It produces an error messge

```
! Xy-pic error: <pos> "A" not defined.
\xyerror@ ...#2}\fi \errmessage {Xy-pic error: #1}
```

So I tried using `\shorthandoff{"}` in several places, and I tried "A and "A" and A" but got messages saying they are not shorthands.  I tried putting just `\shorthandoff` in front of the first offending XY-pic in the file and that had no effect.

I suspect the simplest solution would be to identify which shorthands the Xy-pics conflict with and just disable those.  But I cannot identify them.  I do not know what all the babel french shorthands are.  The fullest description I have found so far is the Babel language definition file for French frenchb.dtx v3.3d, 2017/10/19

at  http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/frenchb.pdf

But it does not list " as a babel french shorthand.

Of course it is possible that tkz-euclide actually requires some specific shorthand that conflicts with some specific Xy-pic command I need to use.  But I hope there is some simple solution.

Comment: `;` is a shorthand in french. So use `\shorthandoff{;}` for your example.

Answer (score 3):

As Ulrike Fischer points out `;` is a shorthand in French.  Indeed the `babel` documentation lists the following symbols as French shorthands:

```
:;?!
```

These are used to implement French spacing conventions for these punctuation symbols.

You can turn these off explicitly with `\shorthandsoff`.  Enclose this in group to limit its scope.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[main=french]{babel}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

{\shorthandoff{:;?!}%
  \xy   ,(100,0);(100,0)
        ,(97,6)="A"
        ,"A"+(-4.5,-1);"A"+(4.5,-1)  *\crv{"A"+(-3.4,-6)&"A"+(3.4,-6)}
\endxy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution i actually used was to rewrite all the Xy-pics as tkz-euclide, so I need not worry about other surprises down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Using proper LaTeX syntax allows doing the `\shorthandoff` operation automatic inside `xy`.

For Ti*k*Z based packages, remember to `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{xy}{\shorthandoff{?!:;}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xy}
   ,(100,0);(100,0)
   ,(97,6)="A"
   ,"A"+(-4.5,-1);"A"+(4.5,-1)  *\crv{"A"+(-3.4,-6)&"A"+(3.4,-6)}
\end{xy}

\end{document}
```